# How to stream user generated videos

Tags: video-streaming

I'm looking for a simple solution to streaming user generated videos to a wide variety of devices.

It seems video standards are still fragmented, so there is no single simple solution. HLS is promising, but Android support is weak. AWS video transcoder as a service would help in building a solution, but still requires lots of infrastructure and moving parts. Wowza is promising, but I'm not sure it provides what I'm looking for.

This seems like a pretty simple task for which there would be an established SaaS vendor, yet I can't find one, nor have I found a thorough description about how to do this yourself.

Comment: And MS has their Azure Media Services (which works well).

Answer (score 2):

I would go for [MPEG-DASH](http://dashif.org/mpeg-dash/), which supports a wide range of devices as listed [here](http://www.bitcodin.com/supported-formats/) and make use of HLS as backup solution. Maybe [bitcodin](http://www.bitcodin.com/) is the SaaS vendor you are searching for - they provide a solution from transcoding to playout.